# Openapi genearter online : (through reference chain: org.openapitools.codegen.online.model.GeneratorInput["authorizationValue"]

Tags: spring-boot, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I am traying to run openapi-generater-online in local machine as SpringBoot Project But getting error while Running  **api/gen/servers/spring**

Error in Terminal

> Cannot construct instance of `java.util.function.Predicate` (no
> Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need
> to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain
> additional type information at [Source:
> (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 5,
> column: 19] (through reference chain:
> **org.openapitools.codegen.online.model.GeneratorInput["authorizationValue"]**->io.swagger.v3.parser.core.models.AuthorizationValue["urlMatcher"])

Request

```
{
  "authorizationValue": {
    "keyName": "string",
    "type": "string",
    "urlMatcher": {},
    "value": "string"
  },
  "openAPIUrl": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.yaml",
  "options": {},
  "spec": {}

}
```

Response

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-02-03T09:24:07.341Z",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/api/gen/servers/spring"
}
```

how should i fix this ??

Comment: If you remove the `authorizationValue` object from your request, does it help?

Comment: no it says "Method Not Allowed"

Comment: When you say "traying to run openapi-generater-online in local machine", do you mean you are deploying the online generator locally?  If so, why?  It's made to use [online here](http://api-latest-master.openapi-generator.tech/index.html).  Using the online generator, and deleting the authorizationValue completely, I was successfully able to generate code.